# how do I use Token2022 with local Anchor tests?

Tags: anchor, token-2022

I've downloaded and built the token 2022 program, and added to the Anchor.toml like this:

```
[[test.genesis]]
address = "TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb"
program = "spl_token_2022.so"
```

However, I'm now getting strange errors:

```
Instruction references an unknown account [xyz pubkey]...
An account required by the instruction is missing
```

and the account listed a) doesn't match up with anything I'm passing, and b) seems to change on each run.

Any thoughts?
Thanks

Comment: also tried this way, same issue : `solana program dump --url mainnet-beta TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA spl_token_2022.so`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue ended up being `init` for an associated token account. As of 0.27.0 `init` uses the regular Token program, so it was trying to create a regular Token ATA when it needed a Token2022 ATA. There is a `token_program` constraint coming in 0.28.0. As a workaround for now, this can be done by created the ATA as a preInstruction (not relying on `init`) using `createAssociatedTokenAccountIdempotent`. Then, all you need are constraints on the ATA being passed in, like:

```
    #[account(
        constraint = ata.owner == some_owner.key(),
        constraint = ata.mint == some_mint.key()
    )]
```